# httpd.conf PHP module not found

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf

I'm trying to set up PHP following the steps from https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions

I installed php **brew install php71 --with-httpd24**

But when I open the file **/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf** the php module is not there, I don't have any **LoadModule php7_module**

What am I missing? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Any solution for this?  I'm in the same boat @andreahg

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your Apache http server is not able to understand what the .php file is because the httpd.conf configuration file is not set to load php module. Make sure php installed `yum install php`

check the existence of php files

```
    $ ls /etc | grep php
    php.d 
    php.ini
```

The most important thing we need to check is that there is a php module

```
    $ ls /etc/httpd/modules/ | grep php
    libphp5.so
```

We need to add the following line somewhere in the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file. Find the place in the document where all the LoadModule commands are by entering /LoadModule and pressing enter, than add the line there.

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
```

Restart apache

```
    $ apachectl restart
```

Comment: Brew is package manager for mac... This yum install php won't work on mac. @Mpho Mokgosi